# Why am I getting alerts about new updates when dnf says I'm up to date?

Tags: fedora, kde, upgrade, dnf

I'm running the KDE spin of Fedora 22. I've run

```
sudo dnf update
```

and it says I'm up to date, but the notification area says I have a bunch of updates that need installed.The screenshot is after just after rebooting.

[image: screenshot of discrepancy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand two things in F22:

1. dnf doesn't autorefresh it's cache like yum does, in fact it goes out of it's way to lie to you sometimes. This means that like apt you actually need to run:

   ```
   dnf clean expire-cache && dnf upgrade
   ```
2. In F22 the desktop isn't using the same package manager as the command line, anymore. They are using the same depsolver, and mostly looking at the same data, so if the repodata matches they should show the same results. But don't be confused if they don't, that's just the new normal.

Comment: huh, that will take some getting used to.